# MySQL Select with filter condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure that looks something like this:

```
Movies
movie_id   genre_id
1             1
2             5
1             2
5             5
1             5
```

So there are many movies to many genres. I need to select movies based on their genres which is of variable length, i.e. I am specified to find movies with `genre_id`: 1 and 5 (for example). However I can't seem to find a way to select them without using many derived tables (as in select for each genre than join them together) or with using an `OR` (which actually means `OR` so ones with 1 but not 5 are selected and vice versa).

Obviously using a `WHERE` won't work since the condition `WHERE genre_id = 1 AND genre_id = 5` is unsatisfiable. How can I do this without using many derived tables (or faster) and is there a general approach to this sort of schema (as I'm pretty sure this is a pretty common way of organizing data).

Comment: This could be solved by using a self join

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: It appears my idea is not as performant as the group by approach. Nevermind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT movie_id
FROM movies
WHERE genre_id IN (1,5)
GROUP BY movie_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

here you can count the number of rows that satisfy the condition genre_id IN (1,5)

Comment: Won't this only select movies strictly with `genre_id` 1 and 5? How can I `SELECT` any `movie_id` with `genre_id` 1 and 5 and others? Thanks a lot, btw!

Comment: @PhilipTsang this will select movies with genre_id 1 and 5 and eventually others, if you want movies with genre 1 and 5 and not any others an additional condition is needed